# Some help making list of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

this is my first question here, I'm new in prolog and I'm doing some homework for school.

I have to make a list of lists and I was fighting with these for 2 days now. Maybe some of you can help me.

This is what I have to do:

With an entry of some thing like this:

```
evaluateList([f(14),_,_,_,_,f(31),_,_],E)
```

E should be:

```
E = [14,[_,_,_,_],31,[_,_]]
```

I have tried to do it, but I cant get the expected result:

```
evaluateList([],[]).
evaluateList([H|T], [S]) :- var(H), do_vars([H|T],S), !.
evaluateList([f(N)|T],[N|S]) :- evaluateList(T,S), !.

do_vars([],[]).
do_vars([H|T],[H|S]) :- var(H), do_vars(T,S).
```

After running the code:

```
evaluateList([f(14),_,_,_,_,f(31),_,_],E)
```

I'm getting:

```
E = [14, _1378, _1384, _1390, _1396, 31, [_1414, _1420]]
```

I mean, I'm getting the 'inside list', but only in the last item.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_vars` should 'eat' elements from the list, *and* return the remainder. So, an additional argument is needed. For instance

```
evaluateList([],[]).
evaluateList(L,[Vs|T]) :- do_vars(L,Vs,R), Vs\=[], !, evaluateList(R,T).
evaluateList([f(N)|T],[N|S]) :- evaluateList(T,S).

do_vars([V|L],[V|S],R) :- var(V), do_vars(L,S,R).
do_vars(R,[],R).
```

Comment: Thanks this really help me!!

Comment: One thing I don't really understand is what value R takes?, because you are are calling `do_vars` with R, but it seems that R stays the same all time, also in `evaluateList`

Comment: OK, I just run the code with `trace` and now I understand the trick, you assign R in the base case of `do_vars`, nice! Thank you again